# Bootstrap modal not fading the background

Tags: bootstrap-modal

When i put the class class="modal fade" the modal does not work. otherwise it works with an opaque background. please give me an insight into this matter.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally id need to see the code to judge.

Try checking your modal open sequence against this one that works perfect for me.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createaccount" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

Please post a fiddle if this doesnt work.